# Geometric properties of independence between random variables

Tags: independence, geometry

Suppose $Y$ and $X$ are two independent random variables.

Are there any geometrical properties (of PDF/CDF/PMF/etc.) that capture this independence?

I know that the Support has to be rectangular and axis-aligned. I.e. knowing a value of $X$ shouldn't reduce or increase the possible outcomes of $Y$. But I was wondering if there are other geometrical properties?

Comment: Support can be a union of disjoint rectangles.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "geometrical" properties?

Comment: @whuber anything that allows me to look at the 3D graph and deduce from there that it's independent

Comment: Could you explain what the "3D graph" might be and what properties one finds by "looking"?  After all, characterizations of independence in terms of PDFs, CDFs, CFs, etc. are clear and simple, so one wonders what you might accept as an answer beyond "the graph is that of a product/sum/etc of functions of the separate variables."